# How can I completely compile a bash project to be distributed?

Tags: bash, compiler-construction

I am trying to compile a bash project into a distributable binary. I tried [shc](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/sources/shc.html), and it worked, except all my `source` statements were broken. I have numerous `source` statements to keep the code base cleaner, but they are broken when compiled with `shc`. How can I compile down my bash project so that instead of having a bunch of `.sh` files, the end user can just have one single file?

Answer (score 2):

Shc is an obfuscator, not a compiler. At the end of the day, it still invokes /bin/sh or whatever, and feeds it your original script. It has not a slightest idea what your script actually does. If it needs an additional file to source, you have to supply it at an appropriate location.

You may want to investigate things like [SHAR](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar). Build anarchive, then compile it with shc if you want.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all you're missing is a facility to expand all your `source` statements.  That should be fairly easy to write if your codebase is fairly consistent in its use of those statements: just write a script to expand them inline and away you go.

Alternatively, just put all your scripts into a single Zip file or tarball and tell the user to extract the contents of that one file, or if even that is too much I'm sure you can imagine a way to encode the zipped contents of all the non-main files into a giant comment at the bottom of the main file, and have it extract what it needs before proceeding.

Or, you know, use the appropriate installer for your system.  Build an RPM for RHEL or a Debian package or a Windows MSI or whatever....